# Adding touch event to GroupObject

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to attach an event listener to a GroupObject, but the event is never fired. Is it not possible to add touch event listeners to GroupObjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to add touch event in GroupObjects, but it need to have something built into it. See the below example, the event is fired only when touch in a rectangle:

```
local group = display.newGroup()

group:insert( display.newRect(100, 100, 50, 50) )
group:insert( display.newRect(200, 200, 70, 70) )
group:insert( display.newRect(150, 350, 90, 90) )

local function onGroupTouch( event )
    print (event.phase, event.target)
end

group:addEventListener( "touch", onGroupTouch )
```

*A way to do this is add a transparent rectangle in the group.*

Comment: The actual shape of the group, or it's content, is a complex shape, drawn using lines (LineObject). Is it possible to detect touches on the group when tapping any of the lines in the group? Or does it only work with rects?

Comment: Currently, display.newLine() objects do not support touch/tap events. Try to draw a rect in background, filled with transparency. `rect.fill = {0,0,0,0.001}`

Comment: I decided to go with polygon objects as children in the group, instead. Unlike lines, they seem to support touch events. But I'll mark your answer as accepted, since the rule is that groups need children to be able to listen to touch events.